# How does Azure App Service work internally in order to reproduce it in self-hosted environment

Tags: azure, webserver, apache2

I'm trying to host my own infrastructure and therefore I was curious of how Azure app service works on the back-end.

I've seen other questions about it but no answer really answered it the way I understand it.

I looked online and and it says that it's basically an http web-server that hosts containers and makes it accessible to the internet.

I was thinking, is it possible to create a web-server with apache2 and put my Blazor or Xamarin.Forms app in a Docker container, upload the container to the web-server, make it accessible to the internet and would that be what Azure app service is ?

Comment: list the thing you must do to host a web site, get a server (with appropriate ram/disk/network throughput,...), install OS, patch OS, install runtime (PHP, JAVA or NodeJ, ... depending on your application), patch runtime, install application dependencies (and patches when needed), Monitor server, application, and I haven't even gotten to security and it does support Docker containers. Does all this and much, much more (not necessarily divulged by Microsoft). Try an open source somewhat equivalent like Openstack (i think ??).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking forward to handle all that, besides all the infrastructure requirements you've listed, I was trying to understand the last part you were referring to as well as the last part of my question. Would that be the road to follow to "reproduce" an app service ?

Comment: to get feel for what involved in implementing your own app service app  to manage docker container is to look under the hood of a similar open source application. Rancher is also a GUI open-source software and pretty much good for what it is meant for, which is managing different resources such as images and containers, https://www.how2shout.com/tools/4-best-docker-gui-tools-to-manage-containers-graphically.html

Comment: Thank you @MZM, I'll look into it. Also could you tell me if let's say I was to not use Docker, could basically a server running Apache run a back-end service such as a web-app or mobile app back-end just like Azure ? Because my question wasn't really about running containers but if that infrastructure was how azure app service does it, docker or not ?